# WordPress shows a count of published items on the site, but the items are not appearing when you click on the "published" link

Tags: posts, dashboard

WordPress shows a count of published items on the site, but the items are not appearing when you click on the "published" link.

[image]

It's showing 39 published posts but when I click on published link, it's not even showing a single post.

Comment: I'd guess some of your plugins are filtering the items out. I'm not really sure what to suggest: check the SQL queries the page is using e.g. with the Query Monitor plugin, or disable plugins to see if that removes the code that's filtering them out.

Comment: Maybe LearnDash is hiding things if you don't have a current license? I don't know it

Comment: have you written a `pre_get_posts` filter somewhere or an SQL filter to change something on the frontend? Or used the `query_posts` function anywhere in your theme or plugins?

Comment: Actually, even after deleting the posts from the dashboard, they are still in the database. I just deleted it from the database and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, deleted posts from the dashboard were not deleted from the database. After deleting unnecessary posts from the database my problem is solved.